# How would you characterise the inverse image of this polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, rational-functions

I am postgraduate student, and in my project I am working with a function in several variables. I would be surprised if it has not been studied extensively, but as I am not a mathematician, I would like to consult with you to find out how I can learn more about it.

Suppose $\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2,\cdots,\vec{y}_m \in \mathbb{R}^d$ are fixed, and $a_i,b_j > 0$ for all $i,j$ then the function is $f:\mathbb{R}^{n \cdot d} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2\cdots,\vec{x}_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m  \frac{a_j}{|\vec{x}_i - \vec{y}_j|} + \sum_{i\neq j} \frac{b_j}{|\vec{x}_i - \vec{x}_j |}.
$$
Here $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. For a given collection $\{\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2,\cdots,\vec{y}_m\}$, I want to find out as much as possible about the inverse images $f^{-1}(c)$ for each real number $c$.

I am not very experienced, so my question is basically this: How would you search for information for this problem? 1. In which field does this question belong? 2. What would you call an equation of this form?

Comment: The absolute values denote Euclidean norm, I assume ?

Comment: @JeanMarie That's right

Comment: Please change the title and remove a few tags. This is not a polynomial or even a rational function (because of the norms that appear throughout). Differential *topology* would be more appropriate, also, than differential *geometry*.

Comment: Just a little comment on terminology : your expressions are by no means "polynomials" ($\sum a_kx^k$,$ \sum a_{pq}x^py^q$...), they are linear combination of inverse distance functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for your comments. It's true that it's more accurate to use precise wording in every circumstance, but generality is restricted each time. I propose we keep the title unchanged until you provide an answer showing that the distinction adds to the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know about Morse functions? 
One can say that $f^{-1}(c)$ is a smooth manifold for all but finitely many values of $c$. If you vary $c$ the $f^{-1}(c)$ will by homotopy equivalent as long as you don't hit any of the points where it is not a smooth manifold. At these values, the preimage will have a singularity and the topology of the preimage will change.

In a simple example with say $d=2$ and $n=1$ one can see what is going on, the general picture is similar but hard to visualize due to higher dimensions.

As suggested by william in comments, the book "Morse Theory" by John Milnor is considered a good source and introduction to the area.

Comment: Just to complement this answer with a reference, a lot of people like the book "Morse Theory" by John Milnor

Comment: That's interesting. You mean $n = 1$, not $m = 1$, I suppose? Otherwise, I won't have enough dimensions

Comment: @MikkelRev I do, I will edit

Comment: Is it correct that such values $c$ where the topology of $f^{-1}(c)$ changes, are precisely the critical values of $f$?

Comment: @MikkelRev Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to contribute to the intuitive understanding of the issue, probably not for you MikkelRev, but for people reading this question desiring to grasp the big figure.

Here is an example in the case where $d=n=2$ with $m=3$ "poles".

Let us give a graphical representation of function $f$ as a surface as shown below :

[image]

I have represented some level lines, in particular at the two saddle points where they take a "lemniscate" form, indicating a singularity, i.e., a topological change.

Generally speaking, above the highest saddle point, the $f^{-1}(c)$ can be described as the distinct "onions peels" that one gets as sections of each "chimney" at various heights by a horizontal plane. This plane can be imagined as an adjustable sea level which can be so high that all islands remain with a single peak.

Comment: Take a look at Gauss-Lucas theorem for example [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/toys/gausslucas.html).

Comment: See as well [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00521.pdf)